# Center align 2 column tables between columns

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I currently have a table which has 2 columns: the left one is right-justified and the right one is left-justified. I'd like to center the table relative to between the two columns: that is, have the divider between the 2 columns in the center of the page. How would I do this?

Comment: Can you post an example of the table and the current column specifications you use?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way of doing it if you know the widths of the columns (via a `p`aragraph style):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/shoframe
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\noindent
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
\hspace*{5cm}%
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}|p{5cm}}
  \raggedleft\lipsum[2] & \raggedright\lipsum[3]
\end{tabular}%
\hspace*{4cm}%
}
\end{document}
```

The idea is that you place everything in a centred box with column-equivalent spaces around it. In the above example, [`showframe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe) was used to identify the text block boundaries and highlight the tabular alignment.

The above would also hold without problem if you currently have an `r|l` column specification. In that instance, rather use

```
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
%...
\noindent
\begin{tabular}
  {>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-.5\arrayrulewidth}|
   >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-.5\arrayrulewidth}}
  % <tabular content>
\end{tabular}
```

The additional `\arraybackslash` corrects the usage of `\\`, redefined by formatting commands like `\raggedleft` and `\raggedright` (amongst others).