# Centering tabular: Why does this work?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

About a month ago, [someone asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57373/center-align-2-column-table-between-columns) how to align a tabular environment around the intercolumn space, which was something I'd been trying to figure out for a brief eternity.  [Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57376/15569) worked more or less fine, though I had to add extra braces around `\raggedright`.  I was wondering, though, if someone could explain to me *why* it worked.

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
\usepackage{array}
%...

\noindent
\begin{tabular}
  {>{\raggedleft}p{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-.5\arrayrulewidth}|
   >{{\raggedright}}p{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-.5\arrayrulewidth}}
    Kindle Edition Available & k \\
    PC/Mac Edition Available & p
\end{tabular}
```

I think it's mostly the math for the paragraph widths that I'm not understanding, but I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain the whole thing in English.  The part that I get is "insert the command `\raggedright` before the first paragraph-style column and `\raggedleft` before the second paragraph-style column"; otherwise I'm in the dark.

If I was unclear about what I'd been trying to do, here's the difference between what that block produces and what this one does:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
    Kindle Edition Available & k \\
    PC/Mac Edition Available & p
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

[image: sample output]

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: If you use `>{{\raggedright}}` then `\raggedright` will be executed in a group and will have *no* effect.

Comment: Oh dear.  Thanks.  When I didn't have the extra braces in, the usual `\\` row-break broke.  I guess that was a non-solution, though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, your `>{{\raggedright}}` does nothing, because `{\raggedright}` is inserted at the start of the cell and the effect is "do nothing", because the declaration is issued in a group. What you need is `\arraybackslash` (I'll explain why later on).

```
\begin{tabular}
  {>{\raggedleft}p{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-.5\arrayrulewidth}|
   >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}}p{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-.5\arrayrulewidth}}
```

You are asking for a two column alignment. Both columns are of type `p` and the width is

> half the current line width, reduced by twice `\tabcolsep` and half `\arrayrulewidth`

You have to know that the structure of a row in your tabular is

> `t C t | t C t`

where `t` denotes a space of width `\tabcolsep`, `C` denotes a cell and `|` denotes the vertical rule, which has width `\arrayrulewidth`.

Thus, since the width of `C` is as stated before, the tabular will be as wide as `\linewidth`:

> t + (0.5L - 2t - 0.5a) + t + a + t + (0.5L - 2t - 0.5a) + t = L

(where L is the line width).

Why `\arraybackslash`? Because `\raggedright` redefines `\\` and so this command could not be used for ending a row. The command `\arraybackslash` restores the correct meaning of `\\`. It's not required in the first column specifier, but you can of course use it also there.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  Thank you for making it clearer.  You've been incredibly helpful with both my silly questions so far, and I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 6):

As **egreg** mentions is his comment, using `>{{\raggedright}}` won't work as you can see when you add more text:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}
  {>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-.5\arrayrulewidth}|
   >{{\raggedright}}p{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-.5\arrayrulewidth}}
    Kindle Edition Available & k \\
    PC/Mac Edition Available & p text some text to test text some text to test text some text to test text some text to test text some text to test
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using simply `>{\raggedright}` for the last column and `\\` to change lines will produce an error since `\centering`, `\raggedright`, `\raggedleft` redefine `\\`; the `array` package provides `\arraybackslash` to restore the meaning, so the following works:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}
  {>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-.5\arrayrulewidth}|
   >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-.5\arrayrulewidth}}
    Kindle Edition Available & k \\
    PC/Mac Edition Available & p text some text to test text some text to test text some text to test text some text to test text some text to test
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]